# Jenkins on Openshift cannot clone repo

Tags: git, jenkins, github, openshift

I'm new to both Jenkins and Openshift so getting tied up a bit.

I have set up Jenkins and pointed it to my github repo, but it can't clone it because I can't find anywhere to store my git credentials, and when I ssh into the jenkins box i can't access ~/.ssh to create new keys or find the ones in there. A further problem may also be that my git repo is private.

I've tried google but there's nothing that I could find. How do I allow Jenkins access my private git repo?

edit: ok i found in manage, then configuration a place for the username and email.  then i have ssh'd in, and used ssh-keygen to create the ssh key in .openshift_ssh and added this to github, first as a normal ssh key, then as a deploy key, and then the same in app-root/data/.ssh but still nothing

Comment: In addition to the 'bounty message': I am not using Github, just pushing code to a remote on OpenShift

Answer (score 5):

You can try and follow "[Building a project hosted on Github using an Openshift Jenkins instance](http://rmaalej.blogspot.fr/2016/01/building-project-hosted-on-github-using.html) " from Ramzi Maâlej.

Make sure Openshift doesn't grant write permission on several folders on a Jenkins instance such as: `.ssh`, `.m2`. (or ssh would not work anyway, because of right on folders "too permissive")
That alone could be the source of your problems, but if that is not enough, read on.

Then:

```
rhc ssh buildserver
mkdir app-root/data/git-ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@yourdomain.com" -f $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/git-ssh/id_rsa
```

Deploy your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/git-ssh/id_rsa.pub` to [your GitHub account](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/)

Create a script `ssh-wrapper.sh` that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID_RSA="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/git-ssh/id_rsa"
KNOWN_HOSTS="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/git-ssh/known_hosts"

ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$KNOWN_HOSTS -i $ID_RSA $1 $2
```

Don't forget to make it executable: `chmod +x ssh-wrapper.sh`

Test it:

```
 ./ssh-wrapper.sh -T git@github.com
Hi Jenkins! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Finally, configure Jenkins:

> go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties` and create a new environment variable called `GIT_SSH` that refers to the location where you created your wrapper.

Comment: Even though it wasn't exactly what I asked :-) I decided now to host the project on BitBucket and your solution works for it too.

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your Jenkins app and use the public key contained in `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.ssh/jenkins_id_rsa.pub` as your Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket deploy key.